# Bilingual Book Options and Pages

Tags: page-layout, readability

I'm working in a bilingual book. Using columns is out of question, due to the book format – small.

Usually you have the text in the original language, followed by the translation (ie the original ends, the translation starts). Or left page the original, right the translation.

I have a block of 6 texts – 12 considering the translations. Each with 2 pages.

I am not sure if this a good strategy, but I was thinking in having the 6 texts in the original language all together and then the other 6 in the translated language. Basically 2 blocks.

I never saw this solution, and would like to know if that would be comfortable for the reader or if you guys have any other thought!

Comment: What is the purpose of the book being bilingual? Your proposed solution sounds awful lot like two books glued together. It might even make more practical sense to a reader to have literally two separate books then. I think most bilingual texts are either to facilitate language learning (usually well known literature) or to reach wider audience (think instruction manual for multiple countries). Your approach might serve the second use case well enough, but not the fist one, so it is important to know the book's purpose.

Comment: I've made some bilingual books in two halves, but they also had two different front pages. So read from one end the book is in language A and if you turn it 180 degrees and read it from the other end it's in language B.

Comment: I own one of these bilingual books and the comfortable thing about it is that you can directly compare the text for learning purposes without turning the page. I would just use the regular method (left page: original, right page: translation) It's the most comfortable thing for learning. If each text is standing alone, it's annoying for the reader to find the point where they struggled with and compare it. Flipping through the pages and all. Just watch out that each page ends with the same content (different languages have different lengths).

Comment: Thank you everyone! Even if quite small, I went for the usual solution (left page original, right page translation).